# Check user input is valid CSS width value

Tags: regex, preg-replace

I'm allowing a user to type in a width value that I need to ensure is a valid CSS width value.

Using regex, how would I get two matches from the user input where `$matches[0] =` a number value AND `$matches[1] =` either `px` or `%`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(\d*)(px|%)?
```

First captured item will be the number, the second captured item will be px or %.

Comment: thanks for your answer - I also just want to match if the user only enters a number (i will assume they meant pixels and will add it after the fact)

Comment: Thanks, I figured the second part out on my own too!